Cors configuration
I've created a web application that consists of a front end and an api, the front end is an app service hosted with the url https://www.pinsandgambits.com/frenchDefence.html
the back end is hosted with a default azure url https://app-pag-master.azurewebsites.net/api/v1
the cors configuration 
seems fine to me, the api is running
https://app-pag-master.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/test/
here's the kicker, it works as expected in most browsers, however not in Duck Duck go and more importantly mobile apps like Instagram and Reddit produce a cors violation

I'm more of a full stack dev, so a bit of a novice when it comes to actually hosting a project, does anyone know what the issue could be or even better how to resolve it?

Your allowed origins have a https addresses, the ones that are blocked have http addresses.
There is also two https address that is blocked, but maybe those url's are not marked as allowed.

lol as soon as I read your post, I asked myself if I'm blind
